Is assigning functions to package variables a Go antipattern even if it makes unit testing easier?
While working on a new microservice written in Go I've gotten into the habit of assigning my functions to global variables and then calling those variables in my actual code.  This has been incredibly helpful for unit testing because I am able to easily mock not only my own functions, but also the functions of libraries my code calls
Here's an example of what I'm doing:
package mycode

import identityLibrary

var credentialFunc = identityLibrary.NewCredential

func myLogic() {
    ...
    credential := credentialFunc()
    ...
}

Then I might write a unit test for myLogic like this:
func myTest(t *testing.T) {
    originalCredFunc := credentialFunc
    defer func() {
        credentialFunc = originalCredFunc
    }

    credentialFunc = func() {
        return errors.New("mock error")
    }

    err := myLogic()
    
    if err == nil {
        t.Error("Expected error, got nil")
    }
}


While this approach has helped me maintain code coverage I'm concerned that I may have stumbled into an anti-pattern by using package/global level variables for my functions.  Certainly reassigning one of those variables to a new function in my own application logic would be disastrous, but if I'm disciplined about doing so only in tests am I ok?
I'm also unsure if there are any performance concerns I might run into at scale?  I think by assigning the functions to global variables I may have made the functions singletons, but I don't know what the performance implications would be?  maybe it depends on whether the function in question is doing something like managing network connections or something?

No, not at all.

I don't think it's helpful to think in terms of "best practice" and "anti-pattern" -- these are just mental shortcircuits for evaluating trade-offs. Typically large code-bases tend towards explicit configuration and few globals (because 1. typically you want to configure multiple packages from various different places so poking and resetting globals across your code-base makes things hard to understand, and 2. you want to run tests in parallel so want independent and isolated components which globals/singletons prevent).

The Go standard library uses the pattern.  Here are some examples:



Package
Function
Test




database/sql
nowFunc
sql_test.go


net
connectFunc and others
dial_unix_test.go



If the standard library uses the pattern, then it's probably not an anti-pattern.

The problem you are having here is that credentialFunc is some kind of global state, so all usual caveats apply, including having an intransparent API. Another might be that it makes calls to T.Parallel impossible without even noticing, so you might introduce hidden test bugs. Not being able to execute tests in parallel has obvious performance implications.
Using global state as a poor mans dependency injection is generally a bad idea. There might be exceptions, so I wouldn't say that every usage is wrong, but I would discourage making a habit out of it. Consider using some DI framework, like wire, for the job.

I like the first half of your answer, but a using DI framework isn't necessarily the best solution.

@jub0bs I'm open for suggestions. wire is just a code generator, you can write everything it does by hand (and check in the generated code), so manual DI is obviously an alternative.

That's more what I had in mind, yeah. "Dependency injection" often doesn't require a framework, esp. in Go.
